# How to disable Drag feature in android rating bar

Tags: android

I am Doing a application, in which my requirement is Rating bar should always have touch event to give rating but it should not have Drag feature to give rating So is there any way, How to Disable Drag feature in Android rating Bar.

Comment: You can use this example in your XML

android:isIndicator="true"
also add this line to the Code

ratingBar.setFocusable(false);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the drag feature, implement `onMotionEvent()` listener on `RatingBar`. Then, get the x coordinates on `ACTION_DOWN` and compare with x coordinates of `ACTION_UP`. If there is a much difference(Drag takes place), return true to handle the event; otherwise return false.

Example:

```
RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
bar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    private float downXValue;

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            downXValue = event.getX();
            return false;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
        {
            // When true is returned, view will not handle this event.
            return true;
        }

        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
             float currentX = event.getX();
             float difference = 0;
             // Swipe on left side
             if(currentX < downXValue)
                 difference = downXValue - currentX;
             // Swipe on right side
             else if(currentX > downXValue)
                 difference = currentX - downXValue;

             if(difference < 10 )
                 return false;

             return true;
         }
         return false;
     }
});
```